# Python - reading text file into dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a huge list of terms that I want to pull from a text file and get them grouped into one of the following groups: Animal, Art, Buildings, Vehicle, Person, People, Food, Glass, Bottle, Signage, Slogan, DJ, Party. I currently have four words in the tester2 file:

plate
pizza
fearns
mixer

Here's my code:

```
keyword_dictionary = {
    'Animal' : ['animal', 'dog', 'cat'],
    'Art' : ['art', 'sculpture', 'fearns'],
    'Buildings' : ['building', 'architecture', 'gothic', 'skyscraper'],
    'Vehicle' : ['car','formula','f-1','f1','f 1','f one','f-one','moped','mo ped','mo-ped','scooter'],
    'Person' : ['person','dress','shirt','woman','man','attractive','adult','smiling','sleeveless','halter','spectacles','button','bodycon'],
    'People' : ['people','women','men','attractive','adults','smiling','group','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
    'Food' : ['food','plate','chicken','steak','pizza','pasta','meal','asian','beef','cake','candy','food pyramid','spaghetti','curry','lamb','sushi','meatballs','biscuit','apples','meat','mushroom','jelly', 'sorbet','nacho','burrito','taco','cheese'],
    'Glass' : ['glass','drink','container','glasses','cup'],
    'Bottle' : ['bottle','drink'],
    'Signage' : ['sign','martini','ad','advert','card','bottles','logo','mat','chalkboard','blackboard'],
    'Slogan' : ['Luck is overrated'],
    'DJ' : ['dj','disc','jockey','mixer','instrument','turntable'],
    'Party' : ['party']
 }

y = 0
while (y < 1):
    try:
        def search(keywords, searchFor):
            for item in keywords:
                for terms in keywords[item]:
                    if searchFor in terms:
                        print item



        with open("C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/tester2.txt") as termsdesk:
                for line in termsdesk:
                    this = search (keyword_dictionary, line)
                    this2 = str(this)
                    #print this2
                    #print item
    except KeyError:
        break
    y = y+1
```

My results should look something like this:

```
Food
Food
Art
DJ
```

But instead I get this:

```
DJ
```

I imagine it's because there's something wrong with my loop. Does anyone know what I need to change? I've tried moving the "while (y<1)" around but I haven't been able to get the results I want.

Comment: Yes it does. "print item" in the 2nd paragraph prints "DJ"

Comment: `line` will have a newline on the end, so won't match. You can strip it off with [**`line.rstrip()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and use the returned value.

Comment: I don't understand. Would I place that directly below the for loop in the 3rd paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove leading / trailing whitespace from the search term. The following works as expected:

```
def search(keywords, searchFor):
    for key, words in keywords.iteritems():
        if searchFor in words:
           print key

with open("tester2.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        this = search(keyword_dictionary, line.strip())
        this2 = str(this)



$ cat tester2.txt 
plate
pizza
fearns
mixer

$ python test4.py 
Food
Food
Art
DJ
```

Also, here is a performance improvement you could consider if you expect the number of search terms to be large relative to the size of the dictionary: you could build a *reverse mapping* from any word to its category.  For example transform:

```
keyword_dict = {'DJ': ['mixer', 'speakers']}
```

into

```
category_dict = {
 'mixer': 'DJ',
 'speakers':'DJ'
}
```

This reverse mapping could be built once at the start and then reused for every query, this way turning your search function into just `category_dict[term]`. This way the look-up will be faster, amortised O(1) complexity, and easier to write.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach would make more sense:

```
keyword_dictionary = {
    'Animal' : ['animal', 'dog', 'cat'],
    'Art' : ['art', 'sculpture', 'fearns'],
    'Buildings' : ['building', 'architecture', 'gothic', 'skyscraper'],
    'Vehicle' : ['car','formula','f-1','f1','f 1','f one','f-one','moped','mo ped','mo-ped','scooter'],
    'Person' : ['person','dress','shirt','woman','man','attractive','adult','smiling','sleeveless','halter','spectacles','button','bodycon'],
    'People' : ['people','women','men','attractive','adults','smiling','group','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
    'Food' : ['food','plate','chicken','steak','pizza','pasta','meal','asian','beef','cake','candy','food pyramid','spaghetti','curry','lamb','sushi','meatballs','biscuit','apples','meat','mushroom','jelly', 'sorbet','nacho','burrito','taco','cheese'],
    'Glass' : ['glass','drink','container','glasses','cup'],
    'Bottle' : ['bottle','drink'],
    'Signage' : ['sign','martini','ad','advert','card','bottles','logo','mat','chalkboard','blackboard'],
    'Slogan' : ['Luck is overrated'],
    'DJ' : ['dj','disc','jockey','mixer','instrument','turntable'],
    'Party' : ['party']
}

terms = {v2 : k for k, v in keyword_dictionary.items() for v2 in v}

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    for word in f_input:
        print terms[word.strip()]
```

This first takes your existing dictionary and make a reverse of it to make it easier to lookup each word.

This will give you the following output:

```
Food
Food
Art
DJ
```

Comment: `types`  is name  of a module in the standard library.  Better use a different name.

Comment: Thanks, missed that, have changed it.