# Python - reading complex lines of text into dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a huge list of terms that I want to pull from a text file and get them grouped into one of the following groups: Animal, Art, Buildings, Vehicle, Person, People, Food, Glass, Bottle, Signage, Slogan, DJ, Party. I currently have four words in the tester2 file:

```
I like sorbet
I am a man wearing a shirt  
Pizza is my favorite meal
formula 1 racing is awesome
steak
```

Here's my code:

```
keyword_dictionary = {
    'Animal' : ['animal', 'dog', 'cat'],
    'Art' : ['art', 'sculpture', 'fearns'],
    'Buildings' : ['building', 'architecture', 'gothic', 'skyscraper'],
    'Vehicle' : ['car','formula','f-1','f1','f 1','f one','f-one','moped','mo ped','mo-ped','scooter'],
    'Person' : ['person','dress','shirt','woman','man','attractive','adult','smiling','sleeveless','halter','spectacles','button','bodycon'],
    'People' : ['people','women','men','attractive','adults','smiling','group','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
    'Food' : ['food','plate','chicken','steak','pizza','pasta','meal','asian','beef','cake','candy','food pyramid','spaghetti','curry','lamb','sushi','meatballs','biscuit','apples','meat','mushroom','jelly', 'sorbet','nacho','burrito','taco','cheese'],
    'Glass' : ['glass','drink','container','glasses','cup'],
    'Bottle' : ['bottle','drink'],
    'Signage' : ['sign','martini','ad','advert','card','bottles','logo','mat','chalkboard','blackboard'],
    'Slogan' : ['Luck is overrated'],
    'DJ' : ['dj','disc','jockey','mixer','instrument','turntable'],
    'Party' : ['party']
 }

def matcher(keywords, searcher):
            for key, words in keywords.iteritems():
                if searcher in words:
                   print key


    with open("tester2.txt") as termsdesk:
        for line in termsdesk:
            term = matcher(keyword_dictionary, line.strip())
```

I want my results to look something like this:

```
Food
Person
Food
Vehicle
Food
```

But instead I just get this:

```
Food
```

I imagine it's because rather making my code make exact matches it needs to make "something like" matches. I'm not sure how I can implement this. Is it possible to do this with an "if" function perhaps?

Comment: you need to divide line to tokens with `line.split(" ")`

Comment: I don't understand. Does the line.spit(" ") go underneath the 2nd line in the 3rd paragraph (after my for loop)

Comment: Your function is being defined every time it goes through the while loop. Couldn't you just place the function outside the loop and what is the objective of the loop? You are doing it only a single time.

Comment: Okay so I removed the loop. It isn't necessary to make this run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - reading text file into dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131784/python-reading-text-file-into-dictionary)

Comment: Why didn't you apply anything  from the answers to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131784/python-reading-text-file-into-dictionary

Comment: I have. the .iteritems() has been added as well as the .linestrip()

This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the mappings makes a lot more sense and is by far more efficient:

```
keyword_dictionary = {'mo-ped': 'Vehicle', 'group': 'People', 'spaghetti': 'Food', 'f-1': 'Vehicle', '6': 'People',
                      '5': 'People', 'five': 'People', 'gothic': 'Buildings', 'seven': 'People', 'adults': 'People',
                      'burrito': 'Food', 'martini': 'Signage', 'f one': 'Vehicle', 'ten': 'People', 'instrument': 'DJ',
                      'dress': 'Person', 'drink': 'Bottle', 'mushroom': 'Food', 'cat': 'Animal', 'glass': 'Glass',
                      'animal': 'Animal', 'pizza': 'Food', 'formula': 'Vehicle', 'meal': 'Food', 'curry': 'Food',
                      '3': 'People', 'sign': 'Signage', 'f1': 'Vehicle', 'biscuit': 'Food', 'bottles': 'Signage',
                      'pasta': 'Food', 'card': 'Signage', 'sculpture': 'Art', '8': 'People', 'apples': 'Food', '9':
                          'People', 'nacho': 'Food', 'mat': 'Signage', 'bottle': 'Bottle', 'shirt': 'Person', 'halter':
                          'Person', 'jockey': 'DJ', 'six': 'People', 'beef': 'Food', 'party': 'Party', 'container': 'Glass',
                      'women': 'People', 'four': 'People', '10': 'People', 'attractive': 'Person', 'mo ped': 'Vehicle',
                      'blackboard': 'Signage', 'two': 'People', 'f-one': 'Vehicle', '4': 'People', 'car': 'Vehicle',
                      'cheese': 'Food', 'plate': 'Food', 'food': 'Food', 'smiling': 'Person', 'bodycon': 'Person',
                      'jelly': 'Food', 'button': 'Person', 'men': 'People', 'people': 'People', 'eight': 'People',
                      'sushi': 'Food', 'chalkboard': 'Signage', 'cake': 'Food', 'sorbet': 'Food', 'turntable': 'DJ',
                      '2': 'People', 'skyscraper': 'Buildings', 'nine': 'People', 'meatballs': 'Food', '7': 'People',
                      'art': 'Art', 'building': 'Buildings', 'sleeveless': 'Person', 'lamb': 'Food', 'disc': 'DJ',
                      'scooter': 'Vehicle', 'asian': 'Food', 'chicken': 'Food', 'food pyramid': 'Food', 'person':
                          'Person', 'ad': 'Signage', 'spectacles': 'Person', 'glasses': 'Glass', 'dog': 'Animal',
                      'logo': 'Signage', 'mixer': 'DJ', 'dj': 'DJ', 'architecture': 'Buildings', 'three': 'People',
                      'fearns': 'Art', 'taco': 'Food', 'f 1': 'Vehicle', 'steak': 'Food', 'cup': 'Glass', 'man':
                          'Person', 'woman': 'Person', 'advert': 'Signage', 'candy': 'Food', 'meat': 'Food',
                      'adult': 'Person', 'moped': 'Vehicle', 'Luck is overrated': 'Slogan'}

with open("test.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in keyword_dictionary:
                print(keyword_dictionary[word])
```

Output:

```
Food  # sorbet
Person # man
Person # shirt
Food # meal
Vehicle # formula
Food # steak
```

If you were to go your route, you should make the list sets and you need to iterate over each word and then each k,v pairing:

```
keyword_dictionary = {
    'Animal' : {'animal', 'dog', 'cat'},
    'Art' : {'art', 'sculpture', 'fearns'},
    'Buildings' : {'building', 'architecture', 'gothic', 'skyscraper'},
    'Vehicle' : {'car','formula','f-1','f1','f 1','f one','f-one','moped','mo ped','mo-ped','scooter'},
    'Person' : {'person','dress','shirt','woman','man','attractive','adult','smiling','sleeveless','halter','spectacles','button','bodycon'},
    'People' : {'people','women','men','attractive','adults','smiling','group','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'},
    'Food' : {'food','plate','chicken','steak','pizza','pasta','meal','asian','beef','cake','candy','food pyramid','spaghetti','curry','lamb','sushi','meatballs','biscuit','apples','meat','mushroom','jelly', 'sorbet','nacho','burrito','taco','cheese'},
    'Glass' : {'glass','drink','container','glasses','cup'},
    'Bottle' : {'bottle','drink'},
    'Signage' : {'sign','martini','ad','advert','card','bottles','logo','mat','chalkboard','blackboard'},
    'Slogan' : {'Luck is overrated'},
    'DJ' : {'dj','disc','jockey','mixer','instrument','turntable'},
    'Party' : {'party'}
 }

def matcher(keywords, searcher):
    for word in searcher:
        for key, words in keywords.items():
            if word in words:
                print(key)
                break


with open("test.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        matcher(keyword_dictionary, line.split())
```

Output:

```
Food
Person
Person
Food
Vehicle
Food
```

Your function does not return anything so setting
            `term = matcher(....` would be setting term equal to `None`

Comparing your logic, using a set as a value and reversing the mappings:

Your code would involve iterating over every line and  word then over every key and value in your dict and another `0(n)` loop using your lists to look for each word in your lists of values.

Using sets as values everything is the same as your own logic except removes the last `O(n)` search replacing it with an `O(1)` set lookup.

The first code simply loops over each line and word with constant work checking if the word is the the dict  and getting each value if the word is in the dict  so it is considerably more efficient.

If you consider any amount of matches as just one you can see if the lists of words is  not `disjoint`  with each set of values:

```
keyword_dictionary = {
    'Animal' : {'animal', 'dog', 'cat'},
    'Art' : {'art', 'sculpture', 'fearns'},
    'Buildings' : {'building', 'architecture', 'gothic', 'skyscraper'},
    'Vehicle' : {'car','formula','f-1','f1','f 1','f one','f-one','moped','mo ped','mo-ped','scooter'},
    'Person' : {'person','dress','shirt','woman','man','attractive','adult','smiling','sleeveless','halter','spectacles','button','bodycon'},
    'People' : {'people','women','men','attractive','adults','smiling','group','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'},
    'Food' : {'food','plate','chicken','steak','pizza','pasta','meal','asian','beef','cake','candy','food pyramid','spaghetti','curry','lamb','sushi','meatballs','biscuit','apples','meat','mushroom','jelly', 'sorbet','nacho','burrito','taco','cheese'},
    'Glass' : {'glass','drink','container','glasses','cup'},
    'Bottle' : {'bottle','drink'},
    'Signage' : {'sign','martini','ad','advert','card','bottles','logo','mat','chalkboard','blackboard'},
    'Slogan' : {'Luck is overrated'},
    'DJ' : {'dj','disc','jockey','mixer','instrument','turntable'},
    'Party' : {'party'}
 }

def matcher(keywords, searcher):
     for key, words in keywords.items():
        if not words.isdisjoint(searcher):
            print(key)



with open("test.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        matcher(keyword_dictionary, line.split())
```

output:

```
Food
Person
Food
Vehicle
Food
```

If you can only get one match per line, to apply the same logic to the reversed mapping approach you just need to add a `break`:

```
with open("test.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in keyword_dictionary:
                print(keyword_dictionary[word])
                break
```

Output:

```
Food
Person
Food
Vehicle
Food
```

Comment: @KrishanVadher, what happens if you have a match for say Person and Food in the same line?

Comment: Than I imagine I would need to write something that makes sure it comes back saying "two keywords found." But because shirt and man are on the same line it should come back with person once.

Comment: But what if you have shirt man and sorbet on one line , then what?

Comment: In that instance, it should be defined as "Person"

Comment: because there are more Persons  than  Foods? If that is the case you need to keep a record of each type found and return the most common but you also have to decide what happens if there is a tie

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following?

```
with open("tester2.txt") as termsdesk:
    for line in termsdesk:
        term = matcher(keyword_dictionary, line.split(" "))
```

Comment: I did yes, it came back with the following error:

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable